# Switching a user in SQL Server fails when accessing through user's default schema in stored proc

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, execute

I'm trying to implement shared API in MS SQL Server 2014 DB. In that architecture, schemas should have similar structures and use shared API owned by dbo whereas at the same time exposes own API. To call one another without qualifying object names, `EXECUTE AS USER` statement is used for context switching to a certain default schema of the current user.

The problem is here: while immediate access with user context switching works fine (e.g. `EXECUTE AS USER` followed by `SELECT * from test_tbl;`), the access through default schema in a stored procedure fails with error `Msg 208, Level 16, State 1`.

Before posting my question, I tried a lot of experiments and tests and  searched MSDN, Web and SQL forums for any clue during several days with no luck.

Scripts for reproducing (`<MDF>` and `<LDF>` requires substitutions with appropritate file paths):

```
-- DB creation
CREATE DATABASE [test_sql]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'test_sql', FILENAME = N'<MDF>' , SIZE = 5120KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'test_sql_log', FILENAME = N'<LDF>' , SIZE = 2048KB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
 COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET ARITHABORT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET  DISABLE_BROKER 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET  READ_WRITE 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET RECOVERY FULL 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET  MULTI_USER 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM  
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME = 0 SECONDS 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] SET DELAYED_DURABILITY = DISABLED 
GO
USE [test_sql]
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.filegroups WHERE is_default=1 AND name = N'PRIMARY') ALTER DATABASE [test_sql] MODIFY FILEGROUP [PRIMARY] DEFAULT
GO

-- Srv login, DB user and schema creation
CREATE LOGIN [test_usr_login] WITH PASSWORD=N'test_usr_login', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[test_sql], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
CREATE USER [test_usr] FOR LOGIN [test_usr_login] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[test_schema]
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [test_schema] AUTHORIZATION [test_usr]
GO

-- Table and stored proc creation
IF OBJECT_id("[test_schema].[test_tbl]", "U") IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [test_schema].[test_tbl];
GO
CREATE TABLE [test_schema].[test_tbl](
    [tc] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

IF OBJECT_id("[dbo].[TA]", "P") IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[TA];
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TA] AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SELECT * FROM 
  (VALUES
  ('CURRENT_USER', CURRENT_USER),
  ('SCHEMA_NAME', SCHEMA_NAME()),
  ('have_UNqualified_select', cast(HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME("[test_tbl]", "OBJECT", "SELECT") as nchar(10))),
   ('have_qualified_select', cast(HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME("[test_schema].[test_tbl]", "OBJECT", "SELECT") as nchar(10)))
  ) AS tmptbl([key], val); -- select permissions fro [test_tbl] of the current user
  SELECT tc as qualified_tc FROM [test_schema].[test_tbl]; -- qualified select
  SELECT tc as UNqualified_tc from [test_tbl]; -- unqualified select fails with Msg 208
END
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[TA] TO [test_usr]
GO
```

Test script:

```
USE [test_sql]
GO
DECLARE @return_value int
execute as login = N'test_usr_login'; -- even when logged in with test_usr_logn, Msg 208 occurs
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[TA]
revert
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Output message:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TA, Line 14 Invalid object name
>   'test_tbl'.
>
> (1 row(s) affected)

Output result:

```
key val
CURRENT_USER    test_usr
SCHEMA_NAME test_schema
have_UNqualified_select 1         
have_qualified_select   1
```

I would appreciate anyone who could bring light to the solution to the problem described.

Comment: You created the table "test_tbl" in the schema "test_schema" but in your procedure you do not specify the schema. I know it is the execute as default schema but if you should specify the schema anyway.

Comment: @SeanLange Shared API concept is implemented through unqualified `test_tbl`: this table should be accessed through the default schema (according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387.aspx)). Otherwise, API can not serve as shared because of the schema name dependency. I found another similar question at [SOF](/questions/27357352/sql-default-schema-resolution-in-stored-procedure) which brings light to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is here: while immediate access with user context
>   switching works fine (e.g. EXECUTE AS USER followed by SELECT * from
>   test_tbl;), the access through default schema in a stored procedure
>   fails with error Msg 208, Level 16, State 1.

The problem here is that you don't know how SQL Server resolves non qualified object name.

When you execute plain sql and use an object without specifying its schema, first user `default schema` is checked, if object is not found, `dbo` schema is checked. If the object is not found even in dbo, the error is raised.

It's different when it comes to stored procedure. If schema is not specified, sp's schema is checked first, if object is not found, `dbo` schema is checked, if it's not found again the error is raised. `User default schema` is never checked in case of stored procedure

Comment: Hence, is there any way to share SP among several schemas?

Comment: Only if you create a copy of this sp in every schema

Comment: If you can change your tables you can use different approach. Instead of non qualified test_tbl table you can create partitioned view. To do this add schema_name column to every table with check constrained. Create a view as union all of all your "similar" tables. Then use this view instead of test_table filtering by appropriate schema that you can calculate prior to use the view. If you use option(recompile) in your query a variable containing schema name will be sniffed and all the tables except the correct one will be excluded from execution plan